# How do I sent large number of messages using sockets?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm setting up a server which should handle a minimum of 10000TPS, which users sockets to communicate with the client.

I have tried creating a client which sends out about 1000 short messages, but it sends about 100-200 messages and the connect gets disconnected, I am guessing there is a problem with the pipe as the client is also receiving a response to each message.

```
public class Client
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

            int n=1000;
            String ip = "192.0.0.1";
            Socket s=new Socket(ip,1111);  
            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
            while(--n >= 0){
                dout.write("DEMODEMO\r\n".getBytes());  
                dout.flush();  
            }
            dout.close();  
            s.close();
  }
}
```

I should be able to send about 10000 messages a second and still receive a response to each message.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nifty guide from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) that you can read. The sample codes are also working perfectly.

On a side note, you can also try throttling your message sent and do an observation whether the connection gets dropped.

```
  `while(--n >= 0){
     try {
       Thread.sleep(10);
       dout.write("SMS_TPS\r\n".getBytes());  
       dout.flush();  
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }                             
   }`
```